# Simple JavaScript algorithm for creating math subtraction equation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I am trying to write an algorithm that will generate a basic subtraction problem. Something like 18-10-4=4. The algorithm should accept the following parameters:

Operand Min, Operand Max, Result Min, Result Max, Number of operands

It should pick multiple random numbers between the oMin and oMax for each operand, and a random number between rMin and rMax for the result. So something like this:

```
var generateSubtractionProblem = function (oMin, oMax, rMin, rMax, oQuantity) {
    var result,
        operands = []
        maxDiff = oMax - (oMin * (oQuantity - 1)),
        minDiff = oMin - (oMax * (oQuantity - 1)),;

    // Pick result
    // Generate operands within range that when subtracted produce result
    if (rMax < minDiff || rMin > maxDiff) {
      console.log('Cannot produce result');
      return {
        result: 2,
        operands: [4, 2]
      };
    }

    if (maxDiff < rMax) {
      console.log('Max difference is ' + maxDiff);
      rMax = maxDiff;
    }

    result = this.randomInRange(rMin, rMax, rPrecision);

    for (var i = 0; i < oQuantity; i += 1) {
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          operands[i] = this.randomInRange((oMin * (oQuantity - 1)) + result, oMax, oPrecision);
          break;
        case 1:
          operands[i] = operands[i - 1] - result;
          break;
        default:
          operands[i] = this.randomInRange(oMin, (oMin * (oQuantity - i)), oPrecision);
          break;
      }
    }

    return {
        result: result,
        operands: operands
    }
}

generateSubtractionProblem(5, 20, 0, 5, 3);
// { result: 4, operands: [18, 10, 4] }... 18-10-4=4
```

Examples in any language would be helpful.

Comment: Are -ve operands allowed?

Comment: What problem are you having coming up with the algorithm?  Are you expecting us to do this for you?

Comment: @Barmar, I was able to come up with something that worked when there were only two operands in the equation, but I can't figure out how to produce > 2 operands that fall within a fixed range and still produce the desired result. I'm not expecting someone to do this for me, But I was hoping I could at least find a link or an example of a similar problem. It seems like a common problem, but I can't find anything quite like it via google/wikipedia/stackoverflow, etc.

Comment: Show what you came up with, and maybe someone will help you generalize it.

Comment: @Barmar, editing original post... thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @RobG what do you mean by -ev?

Answer (score 0):

Start by generating the desired result.

Next generate the first operand. It's min value must be at least `result + operandMin * (numberOfOperands - 1).

Generate the remaining operands. Their range must be between

`(firstOperand - sum(otherOperands)) - (numberOfOperands - numberOfGeneratedOperands) * OperandMax`

and

`(firstOperand - sum(otherOperands)) - (numberOfOperands - numberOfGeneratedOperands) * OperandMin`.